# Nietzsche and "The death of God"

Tags: nietzsche

In the 125th paragraph of "The Gay Science", Nietzsche announces the death of God but I have some doubts. Why God is dead? What is the reason of it? And why did Nietzsche announce it in front of an atheistic public?

Answer (score 1):

When Nietzsche announces the death of God, due to his own contributions and that of his contemporaries and predecessors to philosophical progress, he means reliance on religion as a moral compass and source of meaning, is no longer tenable or relevant. Thus "god is dead", or more so the authority of god in the lives of people, is dead. I think he announced it in front of an atheistic public because he thought they'd be most receptive.

Comment: isn't that his madman speaking?